# Слитно или раздельно: прилагательные с частицей Не

Tags: морфология, частица-не, прилагательные

На одном из сайтов по языку, увидел следующую фразу: "Мальчишкам он показался незнакомым, далеким и не местным." Почему **не местным** пишется раздельно? Это прилагательное с частицей Не, и его можно заменить другим словом, например, **приезжим**. Следовательно, оно должно писаться слитно.  Или там опечатка?

Answer (score 3):

**Нет, не опечатка,** и писаться слитно это слово **не должно и не обязано.** В Нацорпусе частотность вариантов **70:6 в пользу раздельного письма**, а уж писатели знают,  какая форма лучше подходит.

**Хотите сделать замену**, как в правилах говорится?  Тогда получится: ***Мальчишкам он показался незнакомым, далеким и приезжим.*** Хорошо звучит? Вроде бы не очень.

Перед нами однородный ряд синонимов, но построенный **по своим художественным законам**.  Здесь можно  использовать прилагательное «нездешний», но поставить его надо на первое место, тогда остальные признаки будут **пояснять его**. В данном же случае  «не местный»  – это обобщение двух первых признаков,  то есть  «**не из нашего круга, не нашего прихода».**

Отрицать легко, а слитное письмо требует **конкретного содержания**. Вот примеры:

― Маша, ― кротко подтвердила она свой **неместный** статус.

… спросила она, жадно ощупывая мой неказистый, но **неместный** наряд.

Интересны выражения «неместный статус»,  «неместный наряд», там явно чувствуется **утвердительное значении признака**, то есть необычное имя, необычная одежда. Да и однородные отношения (***неказистый, но неместный***) задают утверждение: пусть неказистый, но все равно привлекающий внимание.

И вывод:  правило состоит не в поиске синонима, а в проверке  **утвердительного или  отрицательного  значения конструкции.** Однако в данном случае синтаксис допускает **оба варианта**.  Тогда такая проверка не приводит к определенному решению и задача решается **по смыслу,** а не простым путем **формальной подстановки.**

Answer (score 2):

[В правилах Розенталя](http://old-rozental.ru/orfografia.php?sid=77) сказано:

> 4. Как правило, частица *не* пишется раздельно с относительными прилагательными, выражая отрицание обозначаемого ими признака: *часы не
>    золотые; мёд не липовый; небо здесь не южное*.

Слитное написание "неместный" тоже возможно. Оно больше распространено в специальной литературе (демография, социология, антропология и т.п.), но в последние годы просачивается и в литературный язык. Так, Нацкорпус находит только 6 случаев слитного написания и все после 1995 г. (статистика раздельного написания намного шире).

Comment: А не проще ли было дать автору самому решать вопрос слитно или раздельно? Если он хочет подчеркнуть "отрицательность" - то напишет раздельно. Как вы думаете? Ведь и я бы написал "не местный" в том предложении раздельно (просто это фраза была приведена как иллюстрация правила "замены" ).

Comment: Например: Ненужный и никчемный человек / Нужный, говорите, он человек. Интересно. А по мне, так совсем не нужный (а просто бесполезный). То, что в скобках, мысленное дополнение в голове говорящего.

Comment: @Иваныч Ну так ведь автор сам и решает. Просто для иллюстрации "правила замены" пример подобран неудачно — после предложенной замены предложение становится совсем корявым (стилистически). Если бы автор решил подчеркнуть утвердительное значение, он бы догадался перенести "неместный" в начало списка (см. ответ Sharon). По поводу "мысленного противопоставления" Вы правы — зачастую так и объясняют в правилах раздельное написание.

Comment: Спасибо. Действительно, что касается предложенной мною замены, то там я поспешил: надо было использовать **чужой** или **чужак.** Что же касается *автор и решает,* был бы рад если так, но простых смертных "засыпали" правилами, многие из которых можно заменить вкладываемым в сказанное смыслом. И если заменить, где возможно, правила "смысловым походом," то думаю их стало бы значительно меньше (и проще, как частица Не с глаголами), а грамотность выше.    P.S. Рассуждаю вслух :-).